# how to check if a button is clickable in java,selenium webdriver.ps:check if clickable not wait untill it is clickable

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testing, webdriver

[image]hey i am writing a test case in selenium, the test is based on a shopping website ( http://www.beechtree.pk/ ) and what i want to check in my test is if the size for the product select is available or not. the sizes that are not available are gred out on the website so i understand that they are not clickable anymore. I have tried using isEnabled and isDisplayed condition to check if its clickab;e but they don't work.

ps: i want to CHECK if its clickable(size is available) so that if it is not, my program can choose another size to carry on with the procedure (it is currently choosing randomly) so i don't want to wait for it to become clickable.

Comment: Please post your code as text (formatted as code) instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

As i see you can try to get the class attribute and check if it contains disabledSwatch.

If you need to check only on the sizes that are available then why not use a css selector like:

```css
span[class='swatch']
```

You can use this selector to search elements and click random from them.

Xpath alternative:

```
//*[@class='swatch']
```

or

```
//*[@class='swatch']/..
```

Comment: i am chosing the size randomly from class swatch, using cssSelector.i don't understand your solution though

Comment: You need to specify to match the exact class.

Comment: i have added an image of my code.i will try making edits according to what you say, though i still don't understand you as i am using css selector...

Comment: Yes, but you are selecting the li.swatchContainer which does not tell anything about the state of the size, using my selector you will find only the sizes that are enabled. inspect in the browser and check the selector.

Comment: i tried your way, my program now gives the following error.


Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: also, doesn't li.swatchContainer specify to choose randomly from the list in class swatch. the class swatch also conatins discription of the product, and a button, size discription, which opens a small box that contains the size table...

Answer (score 0):

isEnabled and isDisplayed should work for you. Can you check whether you are selecting the element properly. 
Can you print the text of the button.
Dummy code:

```
    public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenuim\\chromedriver2.3.exe");
    WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver();

    try{
    driver.get("http://register.rediff.com/register/register.php");

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.name("btnemail"));

    boolean actualValue = e.isEnabled();

    if (actualValue)
           System.out.println("Button is enabled");
    else
           System.out.println("Button is disabled");

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    }
catch(Exception ex){
       System.out.println("Exception " + ex.getMessage());
              }
              finally{

                     driver.close();
                     driver.quit();
              }
       }

}
```

Comment: i hard coded to select the disabled/gred out size on website and then in my test program, printed something if it was enabled, it did print it which means my program detects it to be enabled even though it is gred out and is not clickable on the website. same happened when i tested isDisplayed...

Comment: Okay. Can you use Thread.sleep(10000) or driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Follow link http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/wait-commands/

Comment: but i don't want my program to wait or sleep :/
i want it to move on and select some other size if the current is not available :/

Answer (score 0):

To get all the clickable elements:

```
List<WebElement> elms = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.swatch:not(.disabledSwatch)"))
```

To get all the non clickable elements:

```
List<WebElement> elms = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.swatch.disabledSwatch"))
```

To get a random element and check if it's clickable by testing the cursor:

```
List<WebElement> elms = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.swatch"));
boolean disabled = elms.get(i).getCssValue("cursor") != "pointer";
```

To get a random element and check if it's clickable by testing the class:

```
List<WebElement> elms = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.swatch"));
boolean disabled = elms.get(i).getAttribute("class").contains("disabledSwatch");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that instead of checking random sizes to see if they are available, you would check *all* the sizes to see if they are available or not.

From the site, the size is in a `SPAN` element. This size is not available, note the `disabledSwatch` class on the element.

```
<span id="swatch11" class="swatch disabledSwatch" onclick="colorSelected('attribute133','11','','8')">8</span>
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This size is available, the `disabledSwatch` class is not present.

```
<span id="swatch14" class="swatch" onclick="colorSelected('attribute133','14','','10')">10</span>
```

Using this info, we can pull all the sizes and remove those that are not available. This will get us two lists, one with only the sizes that are available and another list with the sizes that are unavailable. Those elements contain text that indicates the size.

Using all this info, the code below pulls all the elements, separates them into available vs unavailable elements, and then pulls the size info from each element and stores those in two lists, `availableSizes` and `unavailableSizes`. From there you can print the lists or verify if certain sizes are available or not, etc.

```
List<WebElement> unavailableElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.swatchesContainer span.swatch.disabledSwatch"));
List<WebElement> availableElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.swatchesContainer span.swatch"));
availableElements.removeAll(unavailableElements);
List<String> unavailableSizes = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> availableSizes = new ArrayList<String>();
for (WebElement e : unavailableElements)
{
    unavailableSizes.add(e.getText());
}
for (WebElement e : availableElements)
{
    availableSizes.add(e.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this work?

```
        List<WebElement> sizes = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
        for(WebElement size : sizes) {
            if(size.isDisplayed() && size.isEnabled()) {
                size.click();
                break;
            }
         }
```